# Datagridview with multiple files attachment column

Tags: c#, vb.net, file-upload, datagridview, attachment

I need a support related to multiple file upload in Datagridview cell .

I need to attached multiple files into datagrid cell .If someone have better idea about that implementation please help .

I saw many example related to file upload but that not support to multiple files upload .

Actually i had separate column for attachments ,user can browse and attached multiple files in datagrid view cell in a selected row after click save link button in row it need to display in data grid preview . But i am stuck with UI implementation and multiple files attachment part in datagrid view .

Please help if someone have better idea about that .

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to have multiple attachments in a single column.  You're talking about a one-to-many relationship so the attachments should be in a separate table.  It's easy to set up two `DataGridViews` so that selecting a row in the parent filters the child grid.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for your quick reply but according to requirement at the moment user request that feature like that way.Anyway if i go with your solution how about the implementation Do you have good example ? Please share with me .Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this an Access DB with an attachment field?

Comment: @TnTinMn no its MS SQL database with VB.net